# Over-thinker in French?

Tags: traduction

My native language being French, I've never felt so uneasy about the translation of a word in English into a French word.

The word `overthinker`, according to Google, translates to `débordeur`.

Alternatively, `over-thinker` also literally translates to `sur-penseur`, but likewise, I feel like there might be a better way to describe it.

I know that I could say something like `Je réfléchis trop` (I think too much), but I feel like it's not as professional as saying `I am an overthinker`.

### TL;DR

Is the best translation of `over-thinker`/`overthinker` `sur-penseur`?

Comment: *Sur-penseur* won't be understood.

Comment: *Je réfléchis trop*, *je me pose trop de questions*.

Comment: @jlliagre exactly my thoughts, I never heard of `sur-penseur` before looking into this.

Comment: Des locutions avec _à outrance_, ou le glissement vers _sur/hyper rationalisation_. Autrement si on concevait ça comme qqc. de positif, c'est l'idée de _voir loin_ peut-être, de penser en profondeur aux impacts, la grande capacité d'analyse, l'attention aux détails etc. J'ai lu dans un lien l'idée de _ressasser_ constamment des idées. Il faut oublier la morphologie du mot anglais et l'aspect usuel du _penseur_, même si on croit aussi que le mot seul est utile pour attirer l'attention sur la réalité du fait que la personne pense beaucoup ou plus que la moyenne en contexte. Merci !

Comment: Side comment, since this is for an interview: mentioning that you are an overthinker might not be an excellent tactic. Even in English I would soften it in a paraphrase.

Comment: over-thinker is a nonce word or made-up word. Google is not a translator. It is a machine. to overthink something is a word. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over-think it is a verb. to overthink something is trop décortiquer quelque chose.

Comment: Overthink isn't just the sum of its parts, thinking too much. It's more about considering or making things more complicated than they are. Failing to recognize or value simplicity and straightforwardness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm French and for me `overthinker` is a way to describe somebody thinking to much. So when you say:

> I know that I could say something like Je réfléchis trop (I think too
> much), but I feel like it's not as professional as saying I am an
> overthinker.

I don't understand how you can be professional with this word. According to [this](http://www.positif-stress.fr/quest-ce-que-loverthinking/) (in French). `Overthinking` is more like a disease than a professional asset.

I'm not sure how you can use this word in a positive way. In French, I will use `Je pense trop` (I'm thinking too much) but I will use it on a negative sense.

Comment: I was about to suggest *qui se prend la tête*. The expression appears in the linked page.

Comment: To put you in perspective, I have an interview soon and the interviewer supposedly likes asking the 3 weaknesses question. One of my weakness is that I overthink things.

Comment: @jlliagre "Se prendre la tête" is an another way to say it and sound better for me

Comment: @TwiN I think you should jut said something like "Je réféchi trop loin et cela me fait parfois perdre du temps" because it's half good and half bad (so for an interview is good). Half bad because you lose time and half good because you think correctly of the thing you need to do. I didn't think a word for "sur-penser" exist but don't use "sur-penseur"

Comment: *Se prendre la tête* is in my opinion the best translation. You should add it to your reply instead of keeping it less visible in comments.

Comment: overthinking is the noun; overthinker is just a nonce word. We don't say; Those people are overthinkers. We do say; Those people are overthinking the problem. And it does not mean: trop de pensées as that blog suggests.

Answer (score 3):

I'm French and during my English course we saw this word "overthinker" in our vocabulary list. The teacher said there was no actual translation for this word.

We would translate that as a "penseur" (which means thinker).

Comment: In my opinion "penseur" lacks the negative message of excess that "overthinker" conveys.

Comment: What English course? Where is the reference to it? I wonder where the teacher found it. I have never seen in in my entire life.

Comment: Yeah, I am beginning to think he might be mistaken on that

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Dessauges Antoine is good and would be understood by a native spaaker.

To emphasize that thinking too much is a trait of character of yours (as is implied by using the adjective form, rather than "I'm overthinking"), you could construct something out of "J'ai tendance à ..." (litt. "I have a tendency to ...").

If you mean a broad attitude in life, I suggest:

> J'ai tendance à compliquer les choses. -- *I tend to overthink things*

which is slightly informal due to "chose".

If instead you are in a professional context and want to emphasize that you spend more time than necessary on the thinking part and not enough on the execution part, this would be my suggestion:

> J'ai tendance à trop réfléchir. -- *I tend to think too much*
>
> J'ai tendance à trop réfléchir avant d'agir. -- *I tend to think too much before I act*

Comment: Ces proposition semblent les plus naturelles. J'aurais bien vu aussi "j'ai tendance à me poser trop de question" dans le même ordre d'idée.

Answer (score 2):

Il m'arrive parfois de *surlire*. (Quand je comprends un propos implicite que l'auteur n'a pas mis.) C'est évidemment un défaut.

On connaît tous le *surproduire* des usines et le *surcorriger* de la langue. (des défauts aussi)

Si je n'ai jamais rencontré de surpenser, j'ai, en revanche, plusieurs fois rencontré

***surréfléchir***.

C'est évidemment un défaut pour Laura Trompette dans *Hello*. Et c'est bien là le sens de over-think.

Mais pas pour Merleau-Ponty qui l'utilise (certes entre guillemets), en opposition à *irréfléchir* pour ce qui concerne le dépassement de la perception sensible immédiate. Et ça... c'est du sport! Mais ça reste un devoir.

Comment: "Surréfléchir" se comprend, c'est donc d'autant plus dommage qu'il n'y ait pas de substantif basé sur le verbe "réfléchir" pour désigner quelqu'un qui réfléchit...

Comment: @Destal : Ha mais si qu'on en a un totalement légitime et bâti comme il faut : "***Réflexionneur***" https://www.google.fr/search?tbm=bks&hl=fr&q=r%C3%A9flexionneur (bon! Oui! Il est déjà pris péjorativement.... alors... je n'ose m'imaginer ce qu'il en irait d'un *surreflexionneur* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

S'il fallait absolument éviter d'utiliser le mot anglais (ce que je trouve absurde, puisque "overthinker" est mieux), je dirais "**suranalyseur**" (suranalyser + analyseur).

Ça a le mérite d'être plutôt clair, même si ça peut laisser une connotation rationnelle (les asiles débordent d'overthinkers. Cela dit les analystes ne sont pas forcément les plus rationnels).

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking for the psychological aspect, it is "Pensées intrusives" .

Have a good day !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/20589)